# How to split up a string and count how many times a word is used?

Tags: c, string, strtok

```
    while(token != NULL)
    {
    //      for(position = strcspn(str,token); position >= 0;
    //              position = strcspn(str, token + 1));
    //      {
    //              str2[position] = count++;
    //      }



    }
```

I think I'm having a logic issue with my code. I'm trying to take in a string from user input and return how many times each word was used and only return each word one time. I think my issue is within the section I have commented out but I'm not entirely sure how to fix or change my code.
For example: 
Input: Hello, my cat is saying Hello.
Output: Hello         2
        my            1
        cat           1
        is            1
        saying        1

Comment: I am sure `str[size] = read_line(str, size);` cannot be right. You are assigning the return value of a line input function, to a single `char`. OTOH if you are trying to assign a pointer returned, to `str`, you cannot, as it is a fixed array.

Comment: The other reason `str[size] = ...` cannot be right, is that you are indexing outside the array bounds. The maximum legal array index here is `str[size-1]`. Do you have warnings enabled? Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which shows what you have tried.

Comment: No, not until you show all the relevant info, but then only about the string input. What is `read_line()`? There are lots of SO questions about counting words in strings.

Comment: I have asked you twice to post the `read_line` function and so I now give up. As to previous questions, click the `c` tag under your question, then in the SO search box near the top right, type in **word frequency**

Comment: I think you need to maintain a count for each element of the array.  You have count as a scalar integer.  Then have maxCount to say which is the largest (of the **count**) .  Both can be updated within the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code and written little differently,
Please have a look.

```
int main()
{
   char haystack[50] = "Hello my cat is saying Hello";
   char needle[10];
   int i = 0,j = 0,k = 0;
   char *ret = NULL;
   int cnt = 0;


   while(haystack[i] != NULL)
   {
       if(haystack[i] == ' ')
       {
           i++;
       }
       else
       {
           //Get each sub strings.
           while((haystack[i] != ' ') && (haystack[i] != NULL))
           {
               needle[k++] = haystack[i];
               i++;
           }
           needle[k] = '\0';
           printf("The substring is: %s", needle);

           //Find how many times the sub string is there in the string 
           while(strstr(haystack, needle) != NULL)
           {
               ret = strstr(haystack, needle);
               //Once the Substring is found replace all charecter of that substring with space.
               for(j=0;j<k;j++)
               {
                   *(ret+j) = ' ';
               }
               cnt++;//Count the no of times the substrings found.
           }
           printf("= %d\n",cnt);
           cnt = 0;
           k = 0;
       }
   }

   return(0);
}
```

I have not taken care for the special characters, You can modify to take care of those.

So I have used the string `"Hello my cat is saying Hello"` instead of `"Hello, my cat is saying Hello."`. Removed the Comma.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

To compute how many times a word is present in a string or line you need a structure to preserve all the different words you have and mainly how many times each word is frequent.

My simple approach, without any optimization, is:

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct wordsDetail
{
    char word[100];
    int freq;
} wordsDetail;

void updateWords(struct wordsDetail s[],  int length, char *token)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < length && s[i].word[0] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (strcmp(s[i].word, token) == 0) {
            s[i].freq++;
            return;
        }
    }
    strcpy(s[i].word, token);
    s[i].freq++;
}

void printResults(struct wordsDetail s[], int length) {
    printf("Words\tFreq\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <length && s[i].word[0] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s\t%d\n", s[i].word, s[i].freq);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    struct wordsDetail myWords[100];
    int wordsDetailLength = sizeof(myWords) / sizeof(wordsDetail);

    const size_t line_size = 1024;
    char *str = NULL;
    int *str2 = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    char *token;

    for (i = 0; i < wordsDetailLength; i++) {
        myWords[i].word[0] = '\0';
        myWords[i].freq = 0;
    }

    if ((str = calloc(line_size, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    printf("Input: ");

    if (scanf("%[^\n]", str) != 1) {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("Output: \n");

    token = strtok(str, " .,!");

    while (token != NULL) {
        updateWords(myWords, wordsDetailLength, token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " .,!");
    }
    printResults(myWords, wordsDetailLength);
    return 0;
}
```

A simple result is:

```
Input: Hello, my cat is saying Hello to my cat.
Output:
Words   Freq
Hello   2
my      2
cat     2
is      1
saying  1
to      1
```